# How to Install Jekyll on Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Jessie)?

Tags: jekyll, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to install Jekyll on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie on it.

I already have the latest LTS nodejs 4.4.7 and I've updated Gem to the latest version by doing:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Then I installed Ruby by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

However, after doing

```
ruby -v
```

I get the version number as ruby 2.1.5. The latest version is 2.3.1.

I tried to install the source code by downloading it from ruby's website then ran the following commands after unzipping the source folder:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After I did that, I went to see what version ruby is, it's still at 2.1.5.

Did anyone else play with Jekyll on a Raspberry Pi 3 before? Though I do have ruby 2.1.5 but I get this error message when I run:

```
jekyll -v
```

"Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have classifier or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem..."

How do I fix this problem? (Sorry, I'm a newbie.)

Answer (score 5):

I was just setting up Raspberry PI yesterday and it worked fine.
I'm running it on Raspberry Pi 3 model B, using RASPBIAN JESSIE (full edition, version May 2016).

Here's commands that I ran from my notes:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
sudo gem install jekyll
sudo gem install bundler
```

I'm not sure if I still need `apt-get install software-properties-common` in there. I was missing `add-apt-repository` command so I ran this.

Comment: Today, after I turned on my Raspberry Pi and ran: ruby -v, it gave out the latest version of 2.3.1. So I guess the version number wasn't recognized right away yesterday. In any case, I tried everything you suggested, but I get the error message when I ran: sudo gem install jekyll. The error message is: "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception) Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources" I've checked that I do have the latest OpenSSL and I do have the latest version of Gem. I also reinstalled ruby using apt-get.

Answer (score -1):

I had to reinstall Raspbian and it worked. Thank you for your help!